# Log deprecations to own file in symfony production

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I have multiple production shops with a Symfony base.
Now i want to write a log file which logs all deprecations.

I want them to appear in a "deprecated.log" file.
These deprecations are read into kibana later.

The Monolog-Readme says

> WARNING (300): Exceptional occurrences that are not errors. Examples: Use of deprecated APIs, poor use of an API, undesirable things that are not necessarily wrong.

(https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md)

So I tried this config

```
monolog:
use_microseconds: false
handlers:
    main:
        type: group
        members: [errors, deprecations]
    errors:
        type: error_log
        level: ERROR
    deprecations:
        type: stream
        level: WARNING
        path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/deprecated.log'
        channels: [php]
```

But the `deprecated.log` was not generated.
What is my mistake? Error-Log seems to work, but not my deprecations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was looking around everywhere, this solution was very nice. But even nicer is that since 5.1 there is deprecations channel

###### As of Symfony 5.1, deprecations are logged in the dedicated "deprecation" channel when it exists

```
monolog:
channels: [deprecation]
handlers:
    deprecation:
        type: stream
        channels: [deprecation]
        path: php://stderr //or file path like '%kernel.logs_dir%/deprecated.log'
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because deprecations are of severity level INFO but you set minimum level WARNING, which is above INFO, so deprecations are ignored.
Following setting should work for you:

```
deprecations:
    type: stream
    level: INFO
    path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/deprecated.log'
    channels: [php]
```